# Android media player, file not found exception, no such file or directory

Tags: android

When setting datasource for the media player, following exception is raised. File not found exception.  "open failed: ENOENT".  No such file or directory.  But the file "kick.mp3" exists in the directory "/home/user/Downloads/".  How to set the datasource.  I am using android on ubuntu 13.10 (Linux)

MainActivity.java

```
 public void play(View v){
      try{
      mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 


            String filePath = "/home/user/Downloads/kick.mp3";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
            inputStream.close();

          mPlayer.prepare();
         mPlayer.start();
         button.setText("pause");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("mPlayer 2", ""+e);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a folder in your projects res folder called raw, then put the mp3 in there

*Edit: After doing this, you have no use for fileinputstream as you can access the file as such:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourfilename);
```

Make sure that yourfilename has no capital letters, as this will throw a lot of errors & not work

Answer (score 0):

String filePath = "/home/user/Downloads/kick.mp3";

The file path you define is in your ubuntu os, It is not file path of android media file.
It is not visible to android OS.

To access you android media first you have to fetch media by passing query on content resolver.

```
/**
     * This defines the music songs query constants
     */
    public interface SongsQuery {
        // External id to be used by loader
        final static int QUERY_ID = SequenceGenerator.getUniqueId();
        final static Uri CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        final static String[] PROJECTIONS = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
        };
        final static String SELECTION = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=" + "?";
        final static String[] SELECTION_ARGS = {"1"};

        final static int ID = 0;
        final static int ARTIST = 1;
        final static int ALBUM = 2;
        final static int ALBUM_ID = 3;
        final static int TITLE = 4;
        final static int TRACK = 5;
        final static int DATA = 6;
    }

public class AndroidArtist implements MediaArtist {

    private final String mName;
    private final URI mArtistURI;
}

public class AndroidMediaItem implements MediaItem {

    private final MediaType mMediaType;
    private final String mName;
    private final AndroidGenre mMediaGenre;
    private final URI mFileURI;
    private final URI mMediaArturi;
}


 private List<MediaItem> mMediaList = new ArrayList<MediaItem>();


    public List<MediaItem> loadInBackground() {
        Cursor genreQuery = getContext().getContentResolver().query(GenreQuery.CONTENT_URI,
                ContentQuery.GenreQuery.PROJECTIONS,
                GenreQuery.SELECTION,
                GenreQuery.SELECTION_ARGS, null);

        if (genreQuery != null) {
            for (genreQuery.moveToFirst(); !genreQuery.isAfterLast(); genreQuery.moveToNext()) {
                String genreName = genreQuery.getString(GenreQuery.GENRE_NAME);
                int genreId = genreQuery.getInt(GenreQuery.GENRE_ID);

                Uri genreMemberUri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);
                Cursor songsQuery = getContext().getContentResolver().query(genreMemberUri,
                        SongsQuery.PROJECTIONS,
                        SongsQuery.SELECTION,
                        SongsQuery.SELECTION_ARGS, null);

                if (songsQuery != null) {
                    for (songsQuery.moveToFirst(); !songsQuery.isAfterLast(); songsQuery.moveToNext()) {
                        File mediaFile = new File(songsQuery.getString(SongsQuery.DATA));
                        if (mediaFile.exists()) {
                            AndroidArtist musicArtist = new AndroidArtist(songsQuery.getString(SongsQuery.ARTIST), null);
                            List< AndroidArtist > mediaArtists = new ArrayList< AndroidArtist >();
                            mediaArtists.add(musicArtist);
                            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sMusicArtworkUri, songsQuery.getLong(SongsQuery.ALBUM_ID));
                            URI mediaArtURI = null;
                            if (albumArtUri != null) {
                                try {
                                    mediaArtURI = new URI(albumArtUri.toString());
                                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            AndroidMediaItem mediaItem = new AndroidMediaItem(MediaType.AUDIO,
                                    songsQuery.getString(SongsQuery.TITLE),
                                    mediaGenre,  URI.create(LibVLC.PathToURI(mediaFile.toURI().getPath())), mediaArtURI);

                            mMediaList.add(mediaItem);
                        }
                    }
                    songsQuery.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (genreQuery != null) {
            genreQuery.close();
        }


        return mMediaList;
    }
```